Splitting up a variable range of time into multiple cells
I need to split up a range of time from a variable input in excel, for example



Start
End




11:00:00
13:00:00



I would like to have the input split up in segments of 30 minute intervals (input is only possible in 30 min intervals as well), so that I have the (time) values 11:00,11:30,12:00,12:30 and 13:00 all in different cells next to or below each other.
I was not able to find anything using the standard excel tools and since I have no experience with programming I can't really use VBA either. Any help is appreciated :)

=SEQUENCE((B2-A2)/TIME(0,30,0)+1,1,A2,TIME(0,30,0))



I had to reformat it a bit but this worked perfectly, thanks!
